# How to convert this raw javascript into jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to convert this raw javascript into jQuery:

```
document.getElementById('myIframe').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML
```

Comment: Why convert a perfectly good, working, single line of javascript to something else that will only be less efficient?

Comment: @jfriend00, Because JQUERY is a buzz word this days... Wow jquery I have to get one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#myIframe')[0].contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML
```

You really should ask yourself why replacing JavaScript to JQuery if it doesn't improve anything. Don't change working code just because everyone talks about jquery.

JQuery is converted to JavaScript, So the executed code will be similar to the code you already have, but less efficient...

Comment: Perhaps this answers the question with some pointless use of jQuery, but why do it this way?

Comment: @jfriend00, He asked I answered. You are right, I added it to the answer 9 sec ago...

Comment: Yup this is why I wanted to convert it in the first place. Just cause I couldn't get it to work with a jquery selector. And reason why I don't want to use getElementById is because that selector has to be class based and I have no control over the element as it is generated from another domain. Of course now my problem is the permission denied error due to same origin policy, sigh :(

Comment: @JakeRow123 - your reason for not using `getElementById` makes no sense.  It does not require or use a class, it uses an id.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes it uses id that's why I can't use it. The iframe which comes from another site has no id only class. In know a custom function can be made that is able to select elements by class too but why do that when jQuery is already in use throughout the rest of the site. As for why use jQuery altogether, lets just say it makes life a lot easier and millions of people would agree with that.

Comment: @JakeRow123 - then next time, please monitor your question and respond to questions promptly when people ask so people can provide answers that are in the right direction.  You provided no context why jQuery made any sense and in the only example you gave, it was dumb to use jQuery.

Comment: @JakeRow123, to select by class name - $('.ClassName')

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few ways.

```
$(document.getElementById('myIframe').contentWindow.document.body).html();

$($('#myIframe')[0].contentWindow.document.body).html();
```

Comment: There is zero reason to convert to a jQuery object so you can use `.html()`.  If your data is in element form, just use `element.innerHTML` to fetch the contents.  Much faster and less code.

Comment: The best answer doesn't just blindly answer what was asked when they were asking to do a stupid thing.  The best answer explains the intelligent thing to do in the context of the question.  If someone asks you where's a good bridge to go jump off of, do you just blindly give them directions?

Comment: @jfriend00 ....that depends on the context which was not given...perhaps that person who wanted to know the best bridge to jump off of was wanting to go bungie jumping or base jumping.  Without context we do not know if the answer is irrelevant or not.

Comment: So, since you didn't ask for any further context, what did you assume was the context of the question (since you seem to think context was missing yet you supplied an answer anyway)?  A good answer either provides several different options for each possible context or asks what the context is before answering so a proper answer can be offered.  I personally can't find any context in which either of your suggestions are a better way of doing things which is why I object to them (I didn't downvote yet though) without any explanatory text about the best way to solve the problem.

Comment: @jfriend00...I didnt need to ask because you asked for me...but OP never answered.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you're looking for [contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/):

```
html = $("#myIframe").contents().find("body").html()
```

Comment: Why is `.contents()` helpful here?

Comment: @jfriend00: "The .contents() method can also be used to get the content document of an iframe, if the iframe is on the same domain as the main page." - from the page I linked to.